# error c2228 left of '.ptr' must have class/struct/union

Tags: visual-studio

I have compilation error in MSVC express 2013, when including "filesystem.h" on any .cpp file.

> "error c2228 left of '.ptr' must have class/struct/union ".

It points to error in `filesystem.h` file, which is part of `"\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include"`

```
template<class _Path> inline
bool remove(const _Path& _Pval)
{   // remove _Pval
-->>    return (_Unlink(_Pval._Ptr()) == 0);
}
```

Thank you for any suggestion.

Comment: Do you have a question? It's a pity you have errors, but we can do nothing about that without _your_ code.

Comment: Hi, I've added the code. It happens just on include <filesystem> in cpp.

Answer (score 0):

After repairing the installation of visual studio, the problem disappeared.